# Terraform CLI version lockdown

Tags: terraform

As some of you might already know, when you execute Terraform CLI it really is finicky about what Terraform version that was used to execute the last plan.

For example I am on Terraform v0.11.8. I haven't updated my Terraform in awhile. A new employee comes onboard and installs the latest Terraform without knowing that our infrastructure is deployed using v0.11.8. The new hire mistakenly executes Terraform with their new version and now I won't be able to execute with my v0.11.8.

Is there a feature in Terraform CLI that reads in the state file, sees that it was executed on v0.11.8, and tells the caller that they're not on the correct version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`required_version` parameter](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/terraform.html#specifying-a-required-terraform-version) in the `terraform` configuration block:

```
terraform {
  required_version = "=0.11.8"
}
```